# JTA Transactions with JPA(Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jta

If I use in persistence.xml a transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" then I can avoid using a non-jta-data-source by using the properties:

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="passsample"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:urlsample"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="usersample"/>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="schemasample"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>        
</properties>
```

The question is if I use a transaction-type="JTA" then is mandatory to use a jta-data-source ?
If is mandatory please tell me why ?
If not what I need to do ?

I am trying to configure an application with glassfish and everything works fine with an external datasource (configured in glassfish), but I would like to configure everything in spring and with the help of properties.

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

For `JTA` transaction type, you have to define `<jta-data-source>`. But if you are using `RESOURCE_LOCAL`(non-JTA), then it is `<non-jta-data-source>`.

JTA is the default transaction type, if none is specified. These element is used to specify the data source, generally a global JNDI name for referencing the data source.

Transaction in JTA can traverse across multiple persistent units/databases & external environment (like JMS). Typically, `JTA` is used in Java EE & `RESOURCE_LOCAL` is used in Java SE environment.

Comment: My question is actually: why when using RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction-type, normally I should have a non-jta-data-source, but as I describe I still have the possibility to use the properties and still being able to connect to my database without having a datasource.
There is such a possibility using JTA transaction-type ? To connect to a database using only properties without a datasource?

Comment: @Mirea Already mentioned earlier, RESOURCE_LOCAL & non-jta are same. JTA is vendor specific & is the responsibility of the container. You're trying is to get direct connection with database, without using datasource. In JTA, you mention all these properties in a configuration file & its container's responsibility thereafter, also using datasource is recommended.